# Call to member function on a non-object

Tags: php, scope, variable-assignment, require-once

I've read several of the threads that already exist with this, or a similar, name. None seems to address my situation exactly.

I'm getting this error from my `utils.php` class.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: debug in /app/www/utils.php on line 89 Fatal error: Call to a member function debug() on a non-object in /app/www/utils.php on line 89
```

I define the variable `debug` like this:

```
require_once('PHPDebug.php');
$debug = new PHPDebug();
```

and then call it (in line 89) like this:

```
$debug->debug($message);
```

The reason I'm so baffled is that I copied and pasted these lines from my `index.php` and that call works just fine.

If you want, I can include links to the `index.php` and `utils.php` files, as well as `PHPDebug.php`.

Comment: First of all before line 89 do var_dump($debug); and post what you get.

Comment: I put that on the line right before, so new line 89, and got: `Notice: Undefined variable: debug in /app/www/utils.php on line 89 NULL`

Comment: Is the declaration of $debug before like 89?

Comment: Well, you get the problem. For a reason that we can't know because you don't post the whole code, $debug var is no more an instance of PHPDebug but is null. Thus, you can't call a method on a null var.

Comment: Could it be because I'm defining $debug outside of any functions in the file (which is not a class) and then I'm accessing $debug (in line 89 etc) within a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your last comment, the solution to your problem is to declare `$debug` as `global` within the function. Thus, you should have something like this:

```
require_once('PHPDebug.php');
$debug = new PHPDebug();

function myfunction()
{
   global $debug;

   // some code

   $debug->debug($message);
}
```

You can read more about global in the [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).